# SQL Statement return 'FALSE' in ELSE block

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, output

this is my SQL code:

```
if NOT EXISTS (select * from tblArtist where Artist= 'The Rolling Stones')
INSERT INTO tblArtist (Artist)
Output inserted.ID, 'TRUE' as isNewEntry
Values('The Rolling Stones')
ELSE (Select ID from tblArtist 
Where Artist = 'The Rolling Stones');
```

this works so far. But if it comes to the else block it should return 'FALSE' as isNewEntry...
now i cannot just use Output keyword because i think it cant be used with select keyword.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
if NOT EXISTS (select * from tblArtist where Artist= 'The Rolling Stones')
INSERT INTO tblArtist (Artist)
Output inserted.ID, 'TRUE' as isNewEntry
Values('The Rolling Stones')
ELSE (Select ID, 'FALSE' as isNewEntry from tblArtist
Where Artist = 'The Rolling Stones');
```